# JavaScript cytoscape doesn't works until resize windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cytoscape.js

i'm a newbie of JavaScript in particular of cytoscape.

I have that code :

```
            <div id="graphicalEditor" class="tab-pane fade">

            <br> Name: <input type="text" id="name"> <input
                type="button" onclick="addnode('name');" value="add node">
            <input type="button" onclick="cy.remove('node');" value="clear">
            <input type="button" onclick="sendData()" value="send"> <br>
            <br>

            <div id="cy"
                style="width: 60em; height: 30em; postion: absolute; border: 1px solid black;"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var cy = cytoscape({

                    container : document.getElementById('cy'),

                    layout : {
                        name : 'preset'
                    },

                    // so we can see the ids
                    style : [ {
                        selector : 'node',
                        style : {
                            'content' : 'data(id)'
                        }
                    } ]

                });
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function addnode(p) {

                    var nome = document.getElementById(p).value;

                    var eles = cy.add([ {
                        group : "nodes",
                        data : {
                            id : nome
                        },
                        position : {
                            x : 100,
                            y : 100
                        }
                    }

                    ]);
                }
            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function sendData() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type : 'GET',
                        dataType : 'json',
                        contentType : 'application/json',
                        url : "/testAjax",
                        data : cy.json()

                    });
                }
            </script>
        </div>
```

Can someone explain me why the div of cytoscape works with js only after i resize the firefox window? After resizing all works fine.

I don't know if it's relevant but this div is in bootstrap nav-tabs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your cytoscape initialization in a DOMContentLoaded eventListener

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    cy = cytoscape({..})
}
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
     
     var cy = cytoscape({

      container : document.getElementById('cy'),

      layout : {
       name : 'preset'
      },

      // so we can see the ids
      style : [ {
       selector : 'node',
       style : {
        'content' : 'data(id)'
       }
      } ]

     }); 
    }
    </script>`    ...  doesn't work :(

Comment: Tried out the following (pretty much the same as what you have) and don't seem to have any problems .. 

https://jsbin.com/vuqeremuko/3/edit?html,console,output

Comment: yes my code works... i know it. My problem is that javascript works only after i have resized my browser page

Answer (score 0):

Try to asign a container to cytospace before load completely the page. 
For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var cy;
  $(document).ready(function(){
     cy = cytoscape({
        container : document.getElementById('cy'),
           layout : {
              name : 'preset'
            },
                // so we can see the ids
           style : [ {
              selector : 'node',
              style : {
                 'content' : 'data(id)'
              }
           } ]
     });
  });
</script>
```